# How to class-dump iPad apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, cocoa, xcode

I am trying to run class-dump an iPad app to explore its architecture. I extracted the .ipa file using The Unarchiver and from inside the Payload folder, I ran class-dump on the .app file. However, I get this error:

```
/*
 *     Generated by class-dump 3.3.3 (64 bit).
 *
 *     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2010 by Steve Nygard.
 */

#pragma mark -

/*
 * File: /Users/jason/Desktop/foo/Foo.app/Foo
 * UUID: 1234567890
 * Arch: arm v7 (armv7)
 *
 *       Objective-C Garbage Collection: Unsupported
 *       This file is encrypted:
 *           cryptid: 0x00000001, cryptoff: 0x00001000, cryptsize: 0x00073000
 */
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: "This file is encrypted" should be a hint...

Comment: Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @jasonbogd: It's encrypted for a reason...

Comment: You might be able to find some class names by running strings on the executable.

Comment: No you won't, because it's encrypted.

Comment: better yet, email the developer and explain to them why they should assist you in your attempts to understand their program. maybe they'll go one step further and provide you with the sources to this program.

Comment: I'd mark this question as unethical

Answer (score 15):

The issue here is that the binary you obtained has been signed and encrypted to be used on the App Store. In order to class dump or disassemble it you will need to obtain an unencrypted binary. The easiest way to get this is to [use GDB to dump the executable](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Crack_prevention#AppStore) when it's running (since the iPhone decrypts the binary to run it).

Of course, this will require a jailbroken device.

Comment: +1 But with the caveat that you shouldn't be doing this unless you a) have explicit permission from the app's author(s) to do that and b) weren't able to simply obtain a direct copy of the source to look at. And even then it's a bit iffy.

Comment: i _personally_ think that this kind of sensitive info should not be given on sites like SO. for one, i always have extra work to do to make sure my app will not be exploited this way, and second, it is _against_ the ethics of software engineering. no war intended, just saying.

Comment: @Viren Security does not rely on hiding methods or obscurity and that does not work in practice.

Answer (score 5):

I have written an article on how you can use gdb and other debugging tools to decrypt an IOS application so you can dump the class info using class-dump-z

http://timourrashed.com/decrypting-ios-app/

Comment: Excellent article! Very useful :)

Comment: Thank you @Firblip, glad you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disassemble it, for example with IDA Pro. It has support for arm.