# Since when is an iOS executable encrypted?

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, app-store

Trying to get class symbols for an iOS executable, I was surprised to get this output for `class-dump`:

```
class-dump theapp/Payload/theapp.app/theapp        
//
//     Generated by class-dump 3.5 (64 bit).
//
//     class-dump is Copyright (C) 1997-1998, 2000-2001, 2004-2013 by Steve Nygard.
//

#pragma mark -

//
// File: theapp/Payload/theapp.app/theapp
// UUID: 446394E7-678B-3437-837C-463134579AE
//
//                           Arch: armv7
//            Minimum iOS version: 4.3.0
//                    SDK version: 6.1.0
//
// Objective-C Garbage Collection: Unsupported
//         This file is encrypted:
//                                   cryptid: 0x00000001
//                                  cryptoff: 0x00004000
//                                 cryptsize: 0x00068000
//
```

`This file is encrypted`: Ok great.
I missed this news about executables now being encrypted.

I'm curious about my dev environment and eco-system:
**Since when is an executable encrypted?**

Is it since:

- a particular date at which the App Store process started to crypt the executable before re-signing it with their certifs? (my bet)
- a particular SDK version?
- an Xcode version?
- an iOS version?
- …

Is it different for the architecture  (armv6, v7…) targeted?

Comment: since when is this a programming question?

Comment: @jcesar If I have a sensitive string in my app, I need to obfuscate it (bad) or choose a more appropriate security design. Or I can know when Apple changed this and decide (or not) to rely on this change.  If there is a more appropriate stackexchange site, please suggest. I thought this might be too technical and deep in stack to be posted on apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: @jcesar and it is a question about a “software tools commonly used by programmers” with only one acceptable answer, that can be sourced and verified.

Comment: Will a date help you with your problem? I don't think so. Are you sure the apps weren't encrypted before? I think all the apps are encrypted when you sign them. Looking on the class-dump github repositorie, nobody has complained about apps being encrypted, if you think it isn't working as expected open an issue https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/issues, but I think you have to decrypt the app before using class-dump http://timourrashed.com/decrypting-ios-app/

Comment: here you have a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776593/how-to-class-dump-ipad-apps

Comment: @jcesar Thank you. This question is related but not exactly what I'm asking. It asks "how to class-dump an encrypted iOS executable", I just want to know when this was introduced.